# Is "MODULE PROCEDURE" used properly in the included code?

Tags: fortran

We use this code in some testing for SCons, but some recent fixes and trying to compile this in gnufortran seem to indicate that `MODULE PROCEDURE MOD_BAR` below wouldn't be recognized by the `USE MOD_BAR`, and perhaps this code is wrong?  It's been a while since I've written Fortran, so any help here is welcome.

```
  PROGRAM TEST
  USE MOD_FOO
  USE MOD_BAR
  PRINT *,'TEST.f'
  CALL P
  STOP
  END
  MODULE MOD_FOO
     IMPLICIT NONE
     CONTAINS
     SUBROUTINE P
        PRINT *,'mod_foo'
     END SUBROUTINE P
  END MODULE MOD_FOO
  MODULE PROCEDURE MOD_BAR
     IMPLICIT NONE
     CONTAINS
     SUBROUTINE P
        PRINT *,'mod_bar'
     END SUBROUTINE P
  END MODULE MOD_BAR
```

Based on feedback below I've split the program and the two modules into three files and that seems valid changing `MODULE PROCEDURE MOD_BAR` -> `MODULE MOD_BAR`
Thanks!

Comment: Are these in a single file? The modules must be compiled *before* they are used. I am sure we have  a duplicate for that. Please use tag [tag:fortran].

Comment: However, the `module procedure` is straight wrong. It is illegal syntax. The `procedure` token makes no sense there.

Comment: It looks like you want `mod_bar` to be a module. Why are you using `module procedure mod_bar` (along with `end module mod_bar`)? Module procedures are completely different things.

Comment: That is, `module procedure mod_bar` is used improperly, but it seems to be a simple typo for `module mod_bar` rather than an improper attempt to implement a submodule. (There will be a name clash with both modules having an accessible `P`, but that's a different problem.)

Comment: This is part of the SCons test suite for Fortran support.  It's old code and we just fixed some module handling defects which exposed that at least to SCons it's not valid, trying to compile in gfortran also errored. Just wanted to make sure it was invalid.  I think the `MODULE PROCEDURE` was put in the file to test that it wouldn't be recognized as a module.

Answer (score 0):

From feedback above this file should actually be 3 files and had a syntax error.

So test1.f90

```
PROGRAM TEST
    USE MOD_FOO
    PRINT *,'TEST.f'
    CALL P
    STOP
END
```

mod_bar.f90

```
MODULE PROCEDURE MOD_BAR
    IMPLICIT NONE
    CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE P
    PRINT *,'mod_bar'
    END SUBROUTINE P
END MODULE MOD_BAR
```

mod_foo.f90

```
MODULE MOD_FOO
    IMPLICIT NONE
    CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE P
    PRINT *,'mod_foo'
    END SUBROUTINE P
END MODULE MOD_FOO
```

Thanks to the commenters for helping sort this out!